# How do I disable swipe gestures for UIPageViewController while keeping data source?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` with `dataSource = self` and two buttons that control the next and previous page transitions. I have a couple view controllers with a drawing view, meaning they require touch gestures. Right now there is a conflict between the two gestures. When the user attempts to draw inside one of the view controllers it attempts to scroll to the next page inside my `UIPageViewController`

How do I disable the swiping gesture for my `UIPageViewController` without disabling the dataSource or disabling the ability to interact with the child view controllers that require gestures for drawing?

Answer (score 0):

make pageViewController a shared object while drawing enumerate it's view for gestures and remove every swipe gesture from it and add it to a global array

then after drawing finishes add the gestures from the array to the pager view again